# How can I automate backups on Pantheon?

Tags: backups

I know I can upgrade my account and have Pantheon do it for me but I want to explore the possibility of writing a bash shell script which uses Terminus commands to backup all my Drupal sites so that I can add to cron on my own schedule.

Comment: Here is the preliminary solution I came up with myself. Pull requests and issue submissions welcome. See https://github.com/uberhacker/pantheon-backup.